# Plot a line graph on python basemap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-basemap

Unable to plot a normal graph on python base map. The code I used to plot base map and line graph is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))

m = Basemap(projection='mill',
            llcrnrlat=5,
            urcrnrlat=37,
            llcrnrlon=67,
            urcrnrlon=99,
           resolution='c')

m.drawcoastlines()
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':phi_pp, 'y':lambda_pp})
fig, m = plt.subplots(m)
m.imshow(m)
m.set_axis_off()
ax_df = fig.add_axes(m.get_position())
ax_df.patch.set_alpha(0)
df.plot('x', 'y', kind='scatter',legend=None, ax=ax_df)
plt.xlabel('IPP Longitude')
plt.ylabel('IPP Latitude')
```

Sample data to plot a line graph over base map is:

```
         x          y
0   15.121270   4246.948356
1   12.103705   4248.927074
2   8.583936    4247.596317
3   18.173364   4244.749973
4   14.175727   4290.142397
```

Comment: Seems like the lat and long in given dataframe is incorrect.

Comment: They are correct!

Comment: @BerlinBenilo can you please come up with some solution?

Comment: Why latitude (y=4246.948356) is so large?